# Java Connection Timeout exceptions

Tags: java, timeout

I am trying to find all Java timeout exceptions:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
java.net.ConnectException
java.rmi.ConnectException
```

Are there other exceptions Java can throw in situations where a connection timeout occurs, or a connection cannot be established?

Comment: You should define your question more clearly.  Are you talking about a particular class or method, or Java in general?  I can write a java program that will throw a `com.mycompany.OutOfCheeseException` when it can't access a particular server...

Comment: @bdares Java in general.

Comment: @Chin Boon: I guess you mean "in the J2SE API"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that a java program will throw a particular exception at all when a connection fails.  It all depends on the implementation.

Here's a plausible method that uses a completely made up exception:

```
public String getImportantStringFromServer(String server) throws ServerIsDeadException{
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        try{
            return getStringFromServer(server);
        } catch(Throwable t){}
    }
    throw new ServerIsDeadException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could always just use the super class of Exception, it may not be necessarily defined, and you may want to catch for different things and deal with them differently, but if you just want to make sure it does get caught just to make sure and throws Throwable, are covered.